# css squares - on resize

Tags: html, css

I want to build a website with 6 squares.
3 in the first row and 3 squares in the second row 2.
If I resize my window these squares must be larger and always adapt themselves to 100%.

The squares must show [like this](http://www.bildupload.com/index.php?image=21f940ea9e7d88dcf7d3779c307524c3).

I have tried this:

```
.sq {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height:96px;
    width:33%;
    background-color:#007CC1;
    margin:0 2px 2px 0;
}

<a class="sq" href="#"></a>
<a class="sq" href="#"></a>
<a class="sq" href="#"></a>
<div class="clear"></div>
<a class="sq" href="#"></a>
<a class="sq" href="#"></a>
<a class="sq" href="#"></a>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

but I don't know how to calculate the height.

How can I do it? Do you have an idea?

Comment: the squares must show like this pic --->  http://www.bildupload.com/index.php?image=21f940ea9e7d88dcf7d3779c307524c3

Comment: Use CSS and relative sizes in percent. - What have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried it 

    .sq { float:left; display:block; height:96px; width:33%; background-color:#007CC1; margin:0 2px 2px 0; }

    <a class="sq" href="#"></a>
    <a class="sq" href="#"></a>
    <a class="sq" href="#"></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <a class="sq" href="#"></a>
    <a class="sq" href="#"></a>
    <a class="sq" href="#"></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>

but idont know how do I calculate the height

Answer (score 3):

Like this may be
The only issue you might have is setting them to be square as the width is a variable you can't set it to the same in the CSS. Might need some jQuery to enforce that. Something like this... untested:

```js
$('.box').each(function(){
$(this).height($(this).width());
});
```

```css
#container {width: 90%;}
.box {float: left; display: block; background: #c00; color: #fff; text-align: center; width: 30%; margin: 0 5% 5% 0;}
.box.last {margin: 0 0 5% 0;}
.clear {clear: both;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<!-- row 1 -->
<div class="box">box 1</div>
<div class="box">box 2</div>
<div class="box last">box 3</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- row 2 -->
<div class="box">box 4</div>
<div class="box">box 5</div>
<div class="box last">box 6</div>
</div>
```