# How to keep image aspect ratio on resize

Tags: html, css

I have this situation in which I want to render a `div` as a square, where the height determines the width. So far the only solution which comes very close is to use an 1px by 1px image:

```
<div class="square">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhA...RAA7">
</div>

.square {
    display:inline-flex;
    height:100%;
    background:darkorange;
}

img {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677792/set-width-according-to-height)) [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uo6vxtn7/26/)

But whatever I try, when I change the height, the square is stretch vertically (not a square any more). You have to hit reload to make it a square again. This seems to happen only in Chrome. Although in the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677792/set-width-according-to-height) it is suggested to use `display: inline-flex` for `.square` it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I did missed something. Any suggestions?

Comment: without playing around with your code i have a question, have you tried using `width: 100%;` `height: auto` instead?

Comment: I did this case with padding-bottom (%) and image proportion. So you should use padding-bottom:100% on .square  in your case and position:absolute; witdth:100%; height:100% on img. https://jsfiddle.net/0zgh8a4t/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Comment: I trick this with some javascript https://jsfiddle.net/3vjh0s3j/.

Comment: And this with some css animation https://jsfiddle.net/aLgd2917/.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This question is not a duplicate of  [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) because in that post its all about the aspect ratio given a certain width. I have a given `height` and no `width`. Only the above 2 comments seem to have a working fix for this issue!